# Encode or somthing to escape slash (/) input in php?

Tags: php, fopen, dir, slash

I'm stack here.

I want to create a file and i use title_input as file_name, but i have problem when create the file to specific folder.

Example:

```
$file_name="Multi purpose Day/Night Security";

$myfile = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/myweb/product/".$file_name.".php", "wb") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

Error:

Warning: fopen(C:/Program Files/xampp/htdocs/myweb/product/Multi-Purpose Day/Night Security.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\myweb\admin\process\do_upload.php on line 28

Unable to open file!

Comment: using a slash which is a directory separator in a file name, is a *real* bad idea

Comment: If `$file_name` is coming from user input, this is a severe security vulnerability as an attacker could make it be something like `"../../config.php"`

Comment: Sephedo's answer is help me, but i must think again to sorting file using time or id, because i put id when file is created in the database.

Andrea, it's not vuln, because the `$file_name` is already encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always just encode the filename to make a valid filename and then decode the filename after you have read from it and this could be as simple as base64ing the filename before and after.

```
$filename = 'Multi purpose Day/Night Security';

// Raw filename
$filename = base64_encode($filename);

// Original filename
$filename = base64_decode($filename);
```